# AWS Opsworks: Load balancing via https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, aws-opsworks

I've setup 2 Rails server instances with an Elastic Load Balancer. I setup SSL via opsworks and when I hit the IP of my instances with https e.g. https://1.2.3.4 I can see the correct certificate.

However, when I hit the domain of the Elastic Load Balancer, a timeout is thrown (loads endlessly).

How should I setup ELB, to properly redirect with https to my instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer was in Security Groups. Besides setting all inbound connections to accept HTTPS protocol and port 443, you have to set the **outbound** connections of the ELB. I found out that they were only to HTTP, and trying to access the instances with HTTPS it failed. I setup a new outbound rule HTTPS to anywhere and it worked!

Comment: Hi Alex, I have the same problem but my outbound connections is set to "All traffic" and also specifying HTTP and HTTPS it doesn't works. Any suggestion? Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you setup the correct port? If yes, then the problem resides somewhere else..